# React - parent class component function change class of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, a parent component and its children components.

In the parent component I store a state for 'active' which holds the id of the active child component. What I'd like to do is have a handleClick function that compares the id of the child component which is being clicked to the value of 'active' and if it's the same, or different, i'd like it to update html className of the child component to achieve a certain style effect (which may include some animation).

Questions:
Is there a way to target the className of a particular child element and update it?

Is it instead better to handle this function in the child itself while storing the id of the 'active' child in the state of the parent component?

If i'm looking to achieve css animations based on the change in className of the child component from one className to another, are there additional considerations, such as including that the animation run on render of the component, if i'm hoping to animate the change this way?

I'm sure there are other ways to approach this and i'm totally open to suggestions on the best approach to achieve the above, but I'll also include that I am just getting started with react and haven't learned about how to use hooks yet. I'm still working with basic functional and class based components.

Thanks in advance and example code with pseudo code below.

example parent component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Task from './openTasks';
import TasksData from './tasks-data';
        
        
    class openTaskAccordion extends Component{
            
      constructor(){
           super()
           this.state = {
                        //holds the id of the currently opened/active item but initialized to -1 since there is no item with an id of -1 at initialization.
                active: -1 
           }
        this.handleClick() = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
            
     handleClick(){
        //if (the id of the clicked task === this.state.active){
        //   change the className of the clicked child component to "closed"
        //    } else {
        //   change the className of the child component with id == this.state.active to "closed", change the className of the clicked child component to "open" and update this.state.active to the id of the now open child component with setState.
        // 
     }
        
            
     render(){
            
                    const Tasks = TasksData.map(task=> <Task key={task.id} task ={task}/>)
                        return(
                            Tasks
                        )
     }
            
            
                
 }
            
     export default openTaskAccordion
```

example child component

```
import React from "react";
import "./OpenTasks.css"

function openTasks(){

        return (
            <div id = {props.task.id} className="tasks" value = {props.task.id}>
                <h1 >{props.task.clientName}</h1>
                <div  className="accordion-item accordion-item-closed" >
                    <h2>{props.task.matter}</h2>
                    <p> - {props.task.matterStatus}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}

export default openTasks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

Parent component

1. `this` isn't bound correctly in constructor for `handleClick`.

Child component.

1. `openTasks` is a functional component, so there is no `this`, or rather, `this` will just be undefined.
2. `openTasks` doesn't consume any of the props passed to it.

## To answer questions

> Is there a way to target the className of a particular child element and update it?

You could do this, but direct DOM manipulations and reaching into other components to change things is anti-pattern in React. The react way is to pass data as props (data including what is or isn't "active") and letting children components handle it locally.

> Is it instead better to handle this function in the child itself while
> storing the id of the 'active' child in the state of the parent
> component?

No, I don't think so, the parent should store the single source of truth about the current "active" child. Pass props to the child, including any callbacks the child could/should call to update state in the parent.

## Solution

The parent component should store the active child, as you've done, but you should pass the active id *and* a callback to the children in order for them to be "clickable" and allow the parent to update what the active child is.

OpenTaskAccordion

1. Fix the `this` binding in the constructor
2. Update `handleClick` to consume a task id to toggle active state of
3. Pass active state and `onClick` callback to `Task`

code

```
class OpenTaskAccordion extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: -1
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // <-- fix this binding
  }

  handleClick(id) { // <-- consume task id
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      active: id === prevState.active ? -1 : id 
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const { tasks = [] } = this.props;

    return tasks.map((task) => (
      <OpenTask
        key={task.id}
        active={active}
        task={task}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
    ));
  }
}
```

OpenTasks

1. Remove all the `this` references since this is a functional component.
2. Consume props object.
3. Add an "active" class if `props.active` matches the current task id.
4. Attach `props.onClick` to *something* clickable to toggle the active state in parent.

code

```
function OpenTask(props) { // <-- consume `props`!!
  return (
    <div
      id={props.task.id}
      className={["tasks", props.active === props.task.id && "active"].join(" ")}
      value={props.task.id}
      onClick={() => props.onClick(props.task.id)} // <-- attach onClick callback
    >
      <h1>{props.task.clientName}</h1>
      <div className="accordion-item accordion-item-closed">
        <h2>{props.task.matter}</h2>
        <p> - {props.task.matterStatus}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-parent-class-component-function-change-class-of-child-component]

CSS used to apply an "animation" for active item toggling. Uses a simple CSS transition on the background color.

```
.tasks {
  transition: background-color ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

## Comment Questions

> In the functional child component, where can I read about what this
> is doing? `className={["tasks", props.active === props.task.id && "active"].join(" ")}`

It is simply a way to create a list of space-separated class names, i.e. "tasks" or "tasks active" from `["tasks"]` or `["tasks", "active"]`.

Some alternative methods include

```
className={`tasks ${props.active === active ? "active" : ""}`}
className={"tasks" + `${props.active === active ? " active" : ""}`}
```

> In the parent class component, what is this doing and why isn't
> `{tasks =[] }` overridden by the data set you created in your
> example?
>
> ```
> const { active } = this.state;
> const { tasks = [] } = this.props;
> ```

`const { tasks = [] } = this.props;` is just a way to provide a defined value for the mapping in the case that `this.props.tasks` is undefined (or falsey), as would be the case if a `tasks` prop ***was not*** passed to the component. So long as `this.prop.tasks` is a defined truth value then that is what is used. Consider this a fallback value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Drew.  Everything you've said seems to make sense to me (despite my poor wording in the question).  As a follow up, I wanted to clarify, when I was saying "is there a way to target the "className" of a child, what I meant was, is there a way to target that className property of the target child and update it, not target the element by className.  In other words, target the child by the id, but change its className (in my example from "accordion-item-closed" to "accordion-item-open" or vice versa.  Thanks again and sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos Ah I see. Yes, you *could* likely do that, but direct DOM manipulations in React are anti-pattern, you should stick to React conventions, such as passing a prop and letting the child component set its classes. The alternative would be to use an array of react refs (passing a ref to each child to attach to an element) and controlling it all in the parent, but IMO that is more cumbersome than simply passing a prop and letting the child take care of it. I updated my answer to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Hey Drew, can you clarify a couple things for me?
in the functional child component, where can i read about what this is doing?
"className={["tasks", props.active === props.task.id && "active"].join(" ")}"

in the parent class component, what is this doing and why isn't "{tasks =[ ] }" overridden by the data set you created in your example?
" const { active } = this.state;
    const { tasks = [ ] } = this.props;"

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos Hi, I tried answering your follow-on questions as best I understood them. You can find them at the end of my answer above. Let me know if I hit the mark.